# How do I configure Mailgun for Moodle?

Tags: email, moodle, mailgun

What is the proper configuration for Mailgun to be used with Moodle? I am using the Bitnami Moodle image on Google Cloud.

- SMTP Hosts: smtp.mailgun.org
- SMTP Security: none
- SMTP Auth Type: Login
- SMTP Username: poastmaster@mymgdomain.com
- SMTP Password: Aslistedintheaccountdetails

I receive this error message.

Error sending password change confirmation email

More information about this error

Debug info: 
Error code: cannotmailconfirm
Stack trace:
line 495 of /lib/setuplib.php: moodle_exception thrown
line 110 of /login/lib.php: call to print_error()
line 81 of /login/forgot_password.php: call to core_login_process_password_reset_request()
Output buffer:

```
 2016-11-18 14:21:25    Connection: opening to smtp.mailgun.org:25, timeout=300, options=array ( ) 2016-11-18 14:23:32  SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110) 2016-11-18 14:23:32 SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Google Compute Engine does not allow outbound connections on ports 25, 465, and 587. By default, these outbound SMTP ports are blocked because of the large amount of abuse these ports are susceptible to.

Port 25 outbound is [blocked on Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/).
Mailgun [mirrors 587, on port 2525](http://blog.mailgun.com/25-465-587-what-port-should-i-use/) - so try using port 2525.

As a quick test you could also try telnetting from the command line to check connectivity, like this:

```
> telnet smtp.mailgun.org 2525
```

Comment: I am seeing in the logs in Mailgun that the messages were accepted and delivered. I am not seeing them in my inbox quite yet but there might be a delay. I am wondering if mailgun prefers TLS at that port or not?

Answer (score 0):

You should attempt to use port `465` instead of port `25` as well as setting encryption to `SSL`.

I haven't used moodle personally but I believe you can do it like this:
`UPDATE mdl_config SET value='ssl://smtp.mailgun.org:465' WHERE name='smtphosts';`

Answer (score 0):

I just did that in a server on digital ocean. So here the solution:

- Configure your DNS and check it on mailgun app;
- In the credentials get your smtp password;
- SMTP host: smtp.mailgun.org:587
- SMTP security: tls
- SMTP Auth Type: Login
- SMTP Username: poastmaster@
- SMTP Password:

The trick here is port 587. I tried everything but just this worked. As a bonus, if you have ssh access to your server you can send emails form terminal with:

```
./swaks --auth \
    --server smtp.mailgun.org:587 \
    --au postmaster@<yourdomain> \
    --ap <smtpcredential> \
    --to anyemail@youwantosend.com \
    --h-Subject: "Teste Moodle" \
    --body 'Testing some Mailgun awesomness!'
```

And, as you are running moodle, if you want to do the same with `php`:

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.mailgun.org:587';                 // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'postmaster@moodle.gpematec.com.br';     // SMTP username
$mail->Password = '<your credetials>';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable encryption, only 'tls' is accepted

$mail->From = 'youremail@yourdomain.com';
$mail->FromName = 'You';
$mail->addAddress('anyemail@youwantosend.com');                 // Add a recipient

$mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // Set word wrap to 50 characters

$mail->Subject = 'PHP subject';
$mail->Body    = 'Email from php!';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
?>
```